# How to assign running values to each columns with for loops in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, both have same shapes.

dfA

```
    2008LG  2007LG  2006LG  2005LG
0   44      65      30      20
1   10      16      56      70
2   65      30      20      122
3   0.0     0.00    679     158
4   0.0     0.00    30      20
```

dfB

```
     2008Net    2007Net      2006Net    2005Net
0           0         0            0    452
1           0         0            0    365
2           0         0            0    778
3           0         0            0    78
4           0         0            0    60
```

The calculation logic is: for each row in dfB , start from the very end `2005Net` column and use `2005LG` - `2005net` and get a value which gets assigned to the first right columns of `2005Net`.

For example: for the first iteration `2005LG` - `2005Net` = 20-452 = `-432` and assign `-432` to `2006Net`. and the second iteration will start from `2006LG` - `2006Net`= 30 - `-432` = 462 and assign to `2007Net`.

below is my code, but it is not cutting it, what exactly is wrong here ?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

for index in tqdm(range(dfA.shape[0])):
    for col_index in reversed(range(4)):
        the_value = 0
        the_value = dfA[dfA.columns[col_index]].iloc[index] - dfB[dfB.columns[col_index]].iloc[index]       
        dfB[dfB.columns[col_index-1]].iloc[index] = the_value
```

Comment: as far as I can see, your code provided the two values you want (`-432` and `462`) at the correct places.

Comment: probably easier if you merge first, are both dataframes the same length? do they share some common key?

Comment: To complicated, why not do dfB["2006Net"] = dfA["2005LG"] - dfB["2005Net"] and then you repeat your process, you can implement your index logic as well in a for loop. So you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```py
for index in reverse(range(4)):
    dfB[index - 1] = dfA.iloc[:, index] - dfB.iloc[:,index]
```

This assume that each column you want to subtract have the same lenght.